# Basic models, understanding the fundamentals of classes (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, model

I understand that it is best practice to refactor as much of my code as possible into the models, however I am relatively new to rails, and programming as a whole.  One of the concepts that seems to be causing me a little trouble is the nature of models, and understanding the scope or the availability of methods and variables.

First of all with a typical method written in the model what are the limitations (scope) that your method can be called on? How does the .self aspect work?  What controllers / views have access to methods defined in the model?

I understand that these are rather basic principles but I believe that my “assumptions” with regard to this are causing me all manner of problems.

Comment: "all manner of problems" - enumerate some of them, and maybe we can address them. The general gist of you post is so wide as to be unanswerable, but in the broadest terms: there are no limitations ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model-View-Controller (**MVC**):

- A **model** holds your data, and any functionality closely related to your data (low level logic)
- A **controller** holds your business logic (high level application logic)
- A **view** holds your presentation layer (user interface)

Views have access to any public model methods.  (Note: all ruby methods are public by default.)  Of course, the model object must be instantiated first in the appropriate controller method, and must be instance variables (i.e. `@person`) and not local variables (i.e. `person`) in the controller.

Controllers also have access to any public model methods.

Protected methods limit access to within the class or within any of its children.  Private methods limit access to within the class, only.

It appears to me that class methods, i.e. `def Person.some_method ...`, are visible anywhere whether or not they are defined as public, protected, or private, although this is counter-intuitive.

---

Regarding your question about self... You can use self for all calls to the model's own methods from inside that model, and you won't go wrong.

e.g. for Person model having first_name and last_name columns:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end

  def parse_name full
    self.first_name, self.last_name = full.split
  end
end
```

However, that's overkill.  You actually don't need to use self for retrieving attributes in ActiveRecord, only for setting attributes, so the following is fine:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def parse_name full
    self.first_name, self.last_name = full.split
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that was great, so self. is only required if i want to change the attribute in the db, not if i simply want to read it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no real limitation in what you can use to access the Model.
Technically you can call methods from your models in your views and your controllers, or other models.

Here's how I look at it:

Models = Your application's logic
Views = Front-end for your models, tying in the pieces that you want the user (or service) to see
Controllers = Glue for Views and Models, calls model data and hands it to the view

You should shy away from calling your models directly from your view.
If you are performing more than 1 or 2 operations on an object in your controller you should probably move it into a model method.

From here, I'd reccomend you picking up a book to learn about what classes do, instance methods, class methods, etc.
I recommend "Learn to Program" from Pragmatic Programmers.
http://pragprog.com/book/ltp2/learn-to-program

From there learn about what MVC is (lots of information out there), which will help with how you understand models, views, controllers, and how they relate.

Comment: Thanks great, thank you, I Shall definately take a look at that!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your questions, it would appear you need to read up on Object-Oriented Programming and the MVC pattern.  These are not exclusive to Rails, of course.